# SQL Database Relationship

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization

I have a DB design question,

I'm trying to design a DB-relationship for companies that have users and need to pay a monthly fee according to a formula. A formula has a name and fee but are not linked to an user but to a company.

Example:

Name: Formula 1

Fee: 5,00

Name: Formula 2

Fee: 10,00

Company XYZ has 2 users with Formula 1 and 2 users with Formula 2. They would need to pay 30,00 .

My initial solution was to link Formula's to users:
[image]

But the problem I have discovered is that Formula's need to be linked to Companies and not to users. This because of the fact that different companies can have different fee's for the same formula.

Example:
Users from company A with Formula 1 need to pay 5 but users from company B with Formula 1 need to pay 10.

This is where I met an obstacle because I didn't seem to have fully trust in my database design, in which I attempted to link Formula_Type with a company (and seperate fee...).

My attempt was to use groups:

[image]

But I faced a problem here:
How or/and where would I split the fee of the Formula? Since they are depending on the company. Also, what foreign key would I use in the USER-table to link it to an Formula, or wouldn't this be possible in my case?

Is what I'm achieving even possible?

Comment: Two questions: 1) If a company has multiple formulas, can some users use one formula and other users use another formula?  2)  Can a user work at multiple companies?

Comment: 1) Yes, one user can have Formula 1 and another user can have Formula 2 

2) No

Comment: Then the model I gave below is what I would use.  If it ever happens that a user can work at multiple companies, you'd remove User.Company_ID and create a User_Company cross-reference table.  Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to apply the design in my app. But wouldn't this mean that I would need to try to also apply these entities ( `Formula_Company` and `User_Formula_Company`) in my code (as in creating them as classes)?

Comment: I think that would depend on your development environment.  I'm a back-end SQL Server developer guy; I design table structures and code stored procedures and server-side functions and leave the front-end development to people who know that part better than I do.

Comment: alright yes. you helped me enough already. thank you very much Brian

Comment: You're very welcome - it was an interesting "how to do this?" puzzle.  Sorry I couldn't help more with the front-end stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this on for size:

```
Company
    ID              -- PK
    Name
    etc.

User
    ID              -- PK
    Company_ID      -- FK to Company
    Last_Name
    First_Name
    etc.

Formula
    ID              -- PK
    Name
    etc.

Formula_Company     -- this allows company-specific fees for different formulae
    ID              -- PK
    Formula_ID      -- FK to Formula
    Company_ID      -- FK to Company
    Fee

User_Formula_Company        -- this identifies which fee a given user is charged
    User_ID                 -- FK to User
    Formula_Company_ID      -- FK to Formula_Company
```